# Distributed programming in Python

Tags: python, distributed

I plan do program a simple data flow framework, which basically consists of lazy method calls of objects. If I ever consider distributed programming, what is the easiest way to enable that in Python? Any transparent solution without me doing network programming?

Or for a start, how can I make use of multi-core processors in Python?

Comment: @Karoly: If I knew any of the technical terms there I wouldn't ask (CORBA, RPC, Cloud).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> lazy method calls of objects

Can be anything at all really, so let's break it down:

### Simple Let-Me-Call-That-Function (RPC)

Well lucky you! python has the one of greatest implementations of Remote Procedure Calls:
[RPyC](http://rpyc.sourceforge.net/).

Just run the server (double click a file, see the tutorial),

Open an interpreter and:

```
import rpyc
conn = rpyc.classic.connect("localhost")
data_obj = conn.modules.lazyme.AwesomeObject("ABCDE")
print(data_obj.calculate(10))
```

And a lazy version (async):

```
# wrap the remote function with async(), which turns the invocation asynchronous
acalc = rpyc.async(data_obj.calculate)
res = acalc(10)
print(res.ready, res.value)
```

### Simple Data Distribution

You have a defined unit of work, say a complex image manipulation.
What you do is roughly create `Node`(s), which does the actual work (aka, take an image, do the manipulation, and return the result), someone who collect the results (a `Sink`) and someone who create the work (the `Distributor`).

Take a look at [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/).

If it's very small scale, or if you just want to play with it, see the `Pool` object in the `multiprocessing` package:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(5)
def f(x):
     return x*x
print(p.map(f, [1,2,3]))
```

And the truly-lazy version:

```
print(p.map_async(f, [1,2,3]))
```

Which returns a Result object which can be inspected for results.

### Complex Data Distribution

Some multi-level more-than-just-fire&forget complex data manipulation, or a multi-step processing use case.

In such case, you should use a Message Broker such as [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).
They allow to you send 'messages' across multiple servers with great ease.

They save you from the horrors of the TCP land, but they are a bit more complex (some, like RabbitMQ, require a separate process/server for the Broker). However, they give you much more fine-grained control over the flow of data, and help you build a truly scalable application.

### Lazy-Anything

While not data-distribution per se, It is the hottest trend in web server back-ends: use 'green' threads (or events, or coroutines) to delegate IO heavy tasks to a dedicated thread, while the application code is busy maxing-out the CPU.

I like [Eventlet](http://eventlet.net/doc/) a lot, and [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) is another option.

Comment: Wow, that's really useful :) It will take me a while to go through these options. But first I finish my dataflow framework. It's pretty cool what can be done with Python.

Answer (score 2):

Try Gearman http://gearman.org/

> Gearman provides a generic application framework to farm out work to
>   other machines or processes that are better suited to do the work. It
>   allows you to do work in parallel, to load balance processing, and to
>   call functions between languages. It can be used in a variety of
>   applications, from high-availability web sites to the transport of
>   database replication events. In other words, it is the nervous system
>   for how distributed processing communicates.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

Please read python.org official resoureces as the starter:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing

Comment: I had seen that. But I don't know what fork/job/cluster/grid means. Maybe you could outline differences and suggest an appropriate solution? The actual library I can find out myself.

Comment: Since your question is vague, you get vague answers. I am afraid that with this unspecific question this is the best answer you might get. I suggest you code your application first and come back with more concrete questions, or spend your time studying different solutions.

Comment: Also for very very basic needs this is enough: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocess#multiprocessing

Comment: The questions isn't vague but should be an indication that I don't know much about that topic (that's why it's a question). So answers could adjust accordingly explaining basic concepts. But maybe you last comment is some start. Thanks.

Comment: @Karoly: I'm not becoming an overall expert in all IT topics just to be able to pick the one I really need. You expect me to become a cluster system admin even though most likely I won't need that? If someone asks a question you always answer to google it?

Comment: @Gerenuk: nobody asked you to become an expert. If you are in doubt, look up the meaning of a basic expression. you don't have to read the whole wikipedia entry to understand a simple concept. eg: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster read the first sentence. if you are more interested, read a paragraph. etc.

Comment: @Gerenuk: also, your question is overly broad, how will you pick the right answer and tool that fits to your needs if you don't understand the basic terms?

Comment: @Gerenuk: Saying "But I don't know what fork/job/cluster/grid means" when talking about parallel processing is like saying "But I don't know what a nail/screw/shelf/wall is" when talking about DIY. You have to be prepared to teach yourself the basic terminology, otherwise you can't hold a conversation and nobody can help you. People aren't asking you to learn "all IT topics" just some terminology.

Comment: As long as there are people who are good at understanding a question and give an answer that is helpful and appropriate, I don't need to teach this skill to others. Being helpful is not as simple as citing information or proposing to google if you don't know what to answer. I've had helpful answers which don't solve the problem completely, but are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Another framework you might consider is [Versile Python](https://versile.com/products/vpy/) (full disclosure: I am a VPy developer). Documentation [recipes](https://versile.com/doc/vpy/current/recipes/index.html) has relevant code examples. With the framework it is easy to set up and connect to services, and you can either define explicit public method interfaces to classes or use the [native python](https://versile.com/doc/vpy/current/recipes/native.html) type framework to remotely access local methods.

Note you would have to set up your program to run in multiple processes in order to take advantage of multiple cores (due to the python global interpreter lock).